# New Date is returning an Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert the date string to Date format.
It works fine, but the result is not deterministic.

```js
console.log(new Date("2020-10-22T00:00:00Z"));
// Thu Oct 22 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

console.log(new Date("2O2O-11-02T00:00:00Z"));
// Invalid Date
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Replace the '2O2O' with '2020' in the second date.

Comment: @OrAssayag it was not O, it was 0 but in bad string format, given from client :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `O` when you should have used `0` (in the second one). I'm not sure how this might have happened...